# Merge lines in auto-fill-mode with GNU Emacs 24.1

Tags: emacs, autofill, emacs24

How do I merge lines when I insert new text between paragraphs in auto-fill-mode?

For example suppose I have the following text:

```
text textᙂtext text text text |
text text text text text text |
text text text text text text |
```

where the `|`'s indicate the maximum line width and `ᙂ` is the cursor. So if I add more text:

```
text text more more more moreᙂtext text text text 
text text text text text text |
text text text text text text |
```

then maximum line width is not respected. I would like something like

```
text text more more more moreᙂ|
text text text text text text |
text text text text text text |
text text text text           |
```

I've tried refill-mode but I don't like how it works, it is too intrusive and doesn't let me add text at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: I'd just press `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`) whenever I need to reformat a paragraph. It's not much extra typing.

Comment: @Juancho, good to know especially when you don't want auto magic destroy something with a document.

Answer (score 1):

If `refill-mode` doesn't let you add text at the end of a paragraph, then please report this via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.